# How to redirect user to /creatPost after he fill in the login form?

Tags: laravel

Im using laravel auth. I have a page specific to login "/login" but I have another page "/createPost" to create a new post. In this create new post page there is a area that only appears if the user is not authenticated and this area shows a login form and also a register form, so that user can login or register before he is allowed to create a new post.

So there are two links "Login" and "create account" that show the appropriate form to the user.

Do you how to redirect the user to this "/createPost" page after the user fill in the login form?

**Create new post page:**

```
@guest
<h3>Create Post</h3>
<p class="text-center">You need to login or create an account first</p>

<!-- Login and create account links -->

<ul class="nav d-flex justify-content-center" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#login" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class=" btn btn-primary">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#register" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Create account</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tabs Content -->

<div class="tab-content registration_body bg-white mt-4" id="tabbb">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

        <form class="clearfix" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
             <!-- form-groups -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn d-block w-100">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade show  clearfix" id="register" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <form method="post" class="clearfix" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
             <!-- form-groups -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn d-block w-100">Create Account</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endguest



 @if(\Auth::check())

   <form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('post.store')}}">
                         fields to create a new post...
   </form>
@endif
```

**Login Controller:**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{  
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

**Register controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

        ]);
    }

}
```

**Full Login Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/createPost');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users ', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/createPost', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@create',
        'as'   => 'post.create'
    ]);

    Route::post('/post/store', [
        'uses' => 'PostController@store',
        'as'   => 'Post.store'
    ]);


});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LoginController.php**

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, User $user)
{
    return redirect()->intended('/home');
}
```

> The [`intended`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users) method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Comment: `intended` method returns the given page after a successful login, meaning that if you try to access an authorized page, you will be asked to fill in the login form, after you do so, you will be redirected to the page you were looking for, no matter what that page was, instead of being redirected to the home page and if you were just to login then you will be redirected to the home page

Comment: Thanks but with that solution its always appearing this: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in . Do you know why?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full code of your `LoginController`?

Comment: But maybe that solution dont work, for example in that create post page I have that part for the "@guest" if the user is not authenticated. But in this same page I have another part for the authenticated user that is inside (if(\Auth::check()) ... endif. I want to show just the content inside (if(\Auth::check()) ... if the user is authenicated. If the user is not authenticated he will see the content inside "@guest".. "@endguest", and in this content there is the login form. After he fill in th login form correctly should be redirected to this same create post page in order to create the post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this.

1) redirect `back` method

```
return redirect()->back();
// or more concise
return back();
```

2) return the previous url via:

```
URL::previous()
```

3) the http refer header

```
request()->headers->get('referer')
```